# Does Unity remember pressed keys?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have my moving, jumping and attacking animations but if when i'm jumping i press atack key, the pj attacks after jumping and I don't want it, so my question is:

Does Unity remember what key did user press? can I avoid it?

Comment: that would largely depend on your code surely

Comment: I´m not sure if I understand your question: You would like to "override" an "old" keypress, if you press another key before the previous is processed?

Comment: can u add code that you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using Animator and setting Triggers with keypress, then they stay in memory and you must to clear them manually.

To reset the trigger, use ResetTrigger(string name) method -
[Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.ResetTrigger.html)

Answer (score 3):

> Does Unity remember what key did user press?

It depends on which Input API is used.

*[`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html):*

Unity remembers what key user presses only in **1** frame when *Input.GetKeyDown* is used. After that frame passes, it's gone and now false. It will only be true again if that key is released and pressed again.

```
void Update()
{
    //True when Space key is pressed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {

    }

    //One Frame has passed, Input.GetKeyDown will be false next time Update() is called
}
```

---

*[`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html):*

Unity remembers what key user presses **every** frame when *Input.GetKey* is used. It will be true only the key is released.

```
void Update()
{
    //True when Space key is pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {

    }

    //One Frame has passed, Input.GetKe will STILL be true next time Update() is called
}
```

---

[*`Input.GetAxis`:*](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)

The behavior is the-same as the *[`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)* function except that it returns *-1* to *1* value instead of `true` or `false`. It **gradually** returns `0` over the next couple of frames when key is released.

---

*[`Input.GetAxisRaw`:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html)*

The behavior is the-same as the *[`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)* function except that it returns *-1* to *1* value instead of `true` or `false`. It returns `0` **immediately**  when key is released.

Comment: Just want to add one thing: `Input.GetAxis` can work like `Input.GetAxisRaw` if Gravity and Sensitivity are both set to 100 in the Input Manager.

Comment: @Galandil Yes, it can. I wrote about its default behavior. For anyone who modifies it to work like `Input.GetAxisRaw`, what's the point of using `Input.GetAxis` since that's the only difference between them.

Comment: there's no point indeed, I posted it just for general knowledge about Unity. :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that info.